# Get access_token from passport-azure-ad.OIDCStrategy for use as bearer token

Tags: node.js, azure, adal, azure-ad-graph-api, passport-azure-ad

** Disclaimer -- I'm new to the world of oAuth and OpenIDConnect -- please be patient if I'm asking a stupid question here.

I want to create a SPA that will request data from an API.  Both the SPA and API are hosted on the same nodejs server.  I want anyone accessing data and/or the app to be authenticated with our AzureAD tenant on Office365.

Currently, I have the authentication piece working using passport-azure-ad.OIDCStrategy.  However, in my app, I would also like to be able to access information from the Microsoft GRAPH api in the server side api code.  However, the OIDC connection that I've already made does not seem to be enough to allow me access to the GRAPH api.  It appears that maybe I need a jwt bearer token.

My question is, do I need to use the access token from the OIDC response to get a bearer token?  If so, how do I go about this (on the server side -- nodejs)?

I tried viewing the example listed in passport-auth-ad for BearerStrategy v2 endpoint.  What confuses me though is that it uses OIDCStrategy!  Does that also return a bearer token?  If so, am I already receiving everything I need in my first OIDCStrategy call?

Thanks for whatever help you can offer!

**Update**

```
https.request({
        hostname: "graph.microsoft.com",
        path: '/v1.0/me/messages',
        port: 443, 
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + req.user.token, Accept: "application/json"}
    },(rs) => {
        console.log("HTTPS Response Status: ", rs.statusCode);
        console.log("HTTPS Response Headers: ", rs.headers)
        rs.on('data', (d) => {
            res.send(d)
        })
    }).end();
```

**Error Message:**

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token validation failure.", ...
```

I confirmed that the token is the same token that was passed as the id_token in the auth callback from Azure.  Any thoughts?

**Update 2**

A few more code snippets to help in diagnosing where I may be going wrong.

**Strategy Config**

```
//Still test code so user management not fully implemented
passport.use("azure", new azureStrategy({
    identityMetadata: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration',
    clientID: "*********************",
    responseType: 'code id_token',
    issuer: "https://sts.windows.net/****************/",
    responseMode: 'form_post',
    redirectUrl: "https://localhost:5070/auth/azure/callback",
    allowHttpForRedirectUrl: true,
    clientSecret: "***************" ,
    state: "************"
},
(iss, sub, profile, claims, accessToken, refreshToken, params, done) => {
    process.nextTick(() => {
        var user = usvc.findUserByAltId(profile.oid, "azure");
        if(!user){

        }
    })
    done(null, {id: profile.oid, name: profile.displayName, email: profile.upn, photoURL: "", token: params.id_token });
}));
```

**Route Definitions**

```
app.get("/auth/azure", azure.passport.authenticate(
 'azure', {scope: ['Mail.Read','User.Read'], failureRedirect: '/'}))

app.post("/auth/azure/callback", azure.passport.authenticate(
  "azure", {scope: ['Mail.Read','User.Read'], failureRedirect: "/error.html"}),
(req, res) => {res.redirect("/user")})
```

Comment: You may want to specify the id_token instead of access_token. Check my answer here on how to get it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76873146/10030693

Answer (score 0):

The OpenIDConnect work grand flow also will returns a JWT token for Authentication & Authorization. You can use the `id_token` in Authentication header for the resources. However, some operations in Graph APIs require an administrator permission.

You can try to run the following script in `PowerShell` to upgrade your Azure AD application's privilege.

```
Connect-MsolService
$ClientIdWebApp = '{your_AD_application_client_id}'
$webApp = Get-MsolServicePrincipal –AppPrincipalId $ClientIdWebApp
#use Add-MsolRoleMember to add it to "Company Administrator" role).
Add-MsolRoleMember -RoleName "Company Administrator" -RoleMemberType ServicePrincipal -RoleMemberObjectId $webApp.ObjectId
```

Comment: Thanks Gary, I was able to find the id_token.  However, I'm trying to connect to graph with the updated code above (see update to my additional question).  I'm getting a 401 but my user should have access to this as I'm able to access my messages via the Graph API portal.

Comment: @GaryLiuMSFT did you see my comment about using the id_token?

Comment: Have you enabled `Mail.Read; Mail.ReadWrite` in your Azure AD application's scope?

Comment: @GaryLiuMSFT, I'm sending Mail.Read and User.Read at this point. `app.post("/auth/azure/callback", azure.passport.authenticate("azure", {scope: ['Mail.Read','User.Read'], failureRedirect: "/error.html"}), 
    (req, res) => {res.redirect("/user")}
)`

Comment: I added the scopes in Azure AD but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: @GaryLiuMSFT - I added the scopes (I think correctly through the Add Application button of the permissions to other applications section of the management console).  It doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Do you need to pass the id_token in exchange for an access_token? The accessToken provided might only be the access for the API, but might not provide the right JWT to access the protected API.

Comment: @TimReilly, actually, id_token can be used as access_token