# Azure AD token verification failed , "level":30,"msg":"authentication failed due to: invalid signature"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am calling backend-api from frontend, for authentication purpose I am using azure-ad onfronted and backend, when I fetch API for first time, request gets authenticated but for next api call, fronted is calling method

```
  const checkAccessTokenandGenerateIfExpired = () => {
    const account = msalInstance.getAllAccounts()[0];
    const accessTokenRequest = {
      scopes: ["User.Read"],
      account: account
    }
    msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(accessTokenRequest).then(function (accessTokenResponse) {
      let accessToken = accessTokenResponse.accessToken;
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
      localStorage.setItem("token", accessToken);
      return toString(accessToken)
    }).catch(function (error) {
      if (error instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
        msalInstance.acquireTokenPopup(accessTokenRequest).then(function (accessTokenResponse) {
          console.log(accessTokenResponse)
          let accessToken = accessTokenResponse.accessToken;
          localStorage.removeItem("token");
          localStorage.setItem("token", accessToken);
        }).catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      }
      console.log(error);
    });

  };
```

Backend returns : - authentication failed

Don't know what's the error in above code, because above block of code is generating new token during second API call

Comment: It's because you are using Microsoft Graph API scope in your accessTokenRequest (User.Read). You need to use a scope for your API, not MS Graph. You can define them in the "Expose an API" page of your API app registration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are using Microsoft Graph API scope in your accessTokenRequest (User.Read). You need to use a scope for your API, not MS Graph. You can define them in the "Expose an API" page of your API app registration.

Comment: Even better, specify the scope to be 'openid'. You can see my detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76873146/10030693